# Вставка текста в форму на веб-странице

Tags: android, form

Здравствуйте.

Имеется приложение с двумя элементами EditText и кнопкой. По нажатию на кнопку нужно передать весь текст, введенный в этом поле, в поле на сайте и нажать кнопку на этой страничке.

**Обновление**

API нету. Сайт не мой, он принадлежит мобильному оператору. Да, пытаюсь сделать через Http post.

В исходниках сайта вижу `"<input id="phoneCode" class="txt" type="text" name="code" maxlength="3" value="" />"`.

Т.е мне нужно писать что-то вроде

```
"List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneCode.value", CodeP));"?
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Http post запросов. Если сайт разрабатываете вы, то проще написать свое API.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Если у сайта нет API, то нужно смотреть его исходники и траффик. Посмотреть какой запрос уходит по клику на кнопку, соответстенно отсылать аналогичный запрос, подставляя свои данные.

**Обновление**

Ну, я бы делал так:
В хроме открываете данный сайт, нажимаете F12, переходите на вкладку network, вводите данные в инпут, нажимаете кнопку. Если после нажатия кнопки никакого редиректа не происходит, то вероятнее всего, что верхний запрос будет тем самым POST, который ушел по нажатию кнопки. Если есть редирект, то нужно поставить паузу в той же панели. Смотрите его структуру и делаете аналогичный запрос из Java кода.